# Probability of union of n independent events, how to prove?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

I need to prove this:
$$P(A_1\cup A_2 \cup \dots \cup A_n) = \sum_{i=1}^n P(A_i) - \sum_{i \neq j} P(A_i \cap A_j) + \sum_{i \neq j \neq k} P(A_i \cap A_j \cap A_k) - $$
$$\dots + (-1)^{n+1} P(A_1 \cap A_2 \cap \dots \cap A_n)$$

That is, the union of n independent events can be expressed this way.

Comment: There are two proofs in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle

Comment: I think you made a typo.

Comment: Fix! Thanks a lot

Comment: Where does independence' come it?

Comment: On right side signs should alternate starting with a plus. So your first  $+$ shoud be $-$ etc. Also I'd use a different notation for saying subscripts all unequal. Could just say $i<j,$ then $i<j<k$ and so on.